# How to convert this code to Swift for saving video?

Tags: video, swift, avfoundation, ios8

I have this code to save a video:

```
(void)saveRecordedFile:(NSURL *)recordedFile {

[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Saving..."
                     maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                     completionBlock:
     ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

             NSString *title;
             NSString *message;

             if (error != nil) {

                 title = @"Failed to save video";
                 message = [error localizedDescription];
             }
             else {
                 title = @"Saved!";
                 message = nil;
             }

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                             message:message
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alert show];
         });
     }];
 });
}
```

I want to convert to swift, and I don't know how to change this lines:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                     completionBlock:
     ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
```

How can I convert the `completionBlock ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)` to swift?

Comment: See my answer. I think it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

i solved its with:

```
  typealias ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock = (NSURL!, NSError!) -> Void

    var complete : ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock = {reason in println(reason)}
    library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum( fileUrl, complete)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write in this ways:

```
assetLibrary.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL, completionBlock: {(url: NSURL!, error: NSError!)  in             
       println("URL %@",url);
       if error != nil{                 
       }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()

        assetsLib.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(postDetail.videoNsurl, completionBlock: { (assetURL: NSURL?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                            alertView.title = "Failed!"
                            alertView.message = error.localizedDescription
                            alertView.delegate = self
                            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                            alertView.show()
            } else {
                if let validAssetURL = assetURL {
                    let alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                            alertView.title = "Saved"
                            alertView.message = nil
                            alertView.delegate = self
                            alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                            alertView.show()
                }
            }
        })
```